# remove mysqli_connect warning displaying in page

Tags: php

```
$mysqlServer = "***";
$mysqlDb = "***";
$mysqlUser = "***";
$mysqlPass = "***";

$conn = mysqli_connect($mysqlServer, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPass) or die("failed to connect to db");
mysqli_select_db($conn, $mysqlDb) or die("failed to connect select db");
```

i have this code, and its working without any problem. But if i try to input a wrong sql server or test it to perform an error. This will display:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
failed to connect select db
```

i don't want the warning to display if ever theres a problem in connecting the sql server. i just want my own error to display.

Comment: put an @ sign in front of the command like `@mysqli_connect`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

2 possible options:

- set the error_reporing level to NOT to show warnings http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- put a `@` sign before mysqli_connect, this supresses the warning message

Comment: IMHO, cases like this, when a function unconditionally triggers a pointless warning for an error condition you already handle, are a legit use case for error suppressor operator. In production servers you normally want to only log warnings that actually relate to a bug in your code.

Answer (score 2):

putting @ sign before each function hide errors

```
$conn = @mysqli_connect($mysqlServer, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPass) or die("failed to connect to db");
```

Comment: Even if this works, PLEASE, don't do this in production code... Actually, try not to do this altogether ^^

Comment: @STTLCU Why not ?

Comment: Because hiding errors makes you blind, you want to handle errors properly, not hide them under the rug.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($mysqlServer, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPass, $mysqlDb);
```

Pass the DB name with the connect as fourth param.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Question is how to disable warning being displayed on page not how to connect to mysql db.